# Entries save but site doesn't update

Tags: craft3

Hey there and thanks in advance. We just moved our site to production as a beta site. The only thing that is different between this site and our local/staging site is the config file. The allowUpdates and allowAdminChanges is set to false. Databases are separate and all sites are running.

We I update entries on prod, they save but my site does not update. When I do the same change on local/dev the changes render on my dev site.

Am I missing something? Does allowUpdates and allowAdminChanges affect whether or not content will be updated on the site? Thought it might be a cache issue but why would it work on dev and not prod?

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

> Does allowUpdates and allowAdminChanges affect whether or not content will be updated on the site?

Nope.

> Thought it might be a cache issue but why would it work on dev and not prod?

Caching is my first thought. Is production behind a CDN, Varnish or some other caching solution that dev is not?

Maybe the [enableTemplateCaching](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#enabletemplatecaching) config setting is set to `false` for non-production environments?

Comment: Looks like the enableTemplateCaching is set to true on staging and prod. I am going to set it to false and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Changed the settings and nothing changed. Going to look into it a little more today and tomorrow. Will update once I figure something out. Thank you for the response.